# How to Prevent Opacity Change of Draggable in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-draggable-flatlist

How can i disable opacity change when i click on a Draggable in React Native? In documentation it just says this and it doesn't work [image]

and i couldn't find anything in Google

Here is what it does when i click

[image]
[image]

But i want it to stay in the same color and opacity when i click on the Draggable. Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I wrapped it with TouchableWithoutFeedback and it worked
[image]

Comment: [why not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)